# copy the content of a directory of maven module project into another module

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I want to copy the content of a directorymodule maven project.
Here is the hierarchy
[image]
I want to copy the content of dist directory into `Tourism/Tourism-Services/src/main/webapp` directory

For this purpose, I tried to use maven-assembly-plugin

here is the extract of the relative pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>./</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>cfg-main-resources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/angular5/tourism/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Here is the extract of assembly.xml file

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>distribution</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>

    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
            <directory>src/main/angular5/tourism/dist</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

The problem is that the content of dist directory is copied in  Tourism/Tourism-Web/target directory. I would like to copy this content in another module, in `Tourism/Tourism-Services/src/main/weapp` directory. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

I succeded in configuring the pom.xml's

Here is an extract of pom.xml within Tourism-Web sub-module

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
        </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>cfg-main-resources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/angular5/tourism/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Here is an extract of assembly descriptor file

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
<id>assembly</id>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>

<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
        <directory>src/main/angular5/tourism/dist</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Here is an extract of pom.xml of Tourism-Services sub-module

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tourism-guide</groupId>
        <artifactId>tourism-web</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <classifier>assembly</classifier>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>   
..................
's..................
    </dependencies>
<build>
    <!-- Set the name of the war, used as the context root when the app is 
        deployed -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

<plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <id>unpack-angular-dist-resources</id>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <phase>compile</phase>
                  <configuration>
                      <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</outputDirectory>
                      <includeArtifactIds>tourism-web</includeArtifactIds>
                      <includeGroupIds>${project.groupId}</includeGroupIds>
                      <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
                      <excludeTypes>pom</excludeTypes>
                      <scope>compile</scope>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thank you for reading